# I'm Getting 404 Not Found for Flask Code and I can't figure out why

Tags: python, flask, http-status-code-404

I am attempting to teach myself flask from Medium and YouTube tutorials, and keep running into the same error.

[Screenshot of 404 Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FygOj.png)

Normally, I would assume I messed up, made a spelling mistake, and shouldn't embarrass myself by asking how to fix it on a public forum, but I literally copy-pasted the code without making any changes.

I found a [Medium post](https://medium.com/bhavaniravi/build-your-1st-python-web-app-with-flask-b039d11f101c) that walks you through step-by-step with simple instructions and ran the code

```
from flask import Flask           # import flask
app = Flask(__name__)             # create an app instance

@app.route("/")                   # at the end point /
def hello():                      # call method hello
    return "Hello World!"         # which returns "hello world"
if __name__ == "__main__":        # on running python app.py
    app.run()                     # run the flask app
```

and continue to get the same error. Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

[Screenshot of Pycharm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4I7q.png)

Comment: Are you sure your app is running on port 5000?

Comment: Did you run `flask run` in terminal?

Comment: Yes to the first, I have not idea to the second. I've only done what the tutorial told me to. I'll try to add the Pycharm screenshot.

Comment: better you set port=5000 manually and set debug=True in app.run i.e app.run(port=5000,debug=True).Think this will work.else we check again

Comment: nothing wrong with the code.I copied the same code and it's just worked fine.If you check in google you would find 404 generally occurs if server does not understand the request or access not granted.My suggestion to you would be to open port 5000 in firewall for inbound rules.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try changing `app.run()` to `app.run(debug=True)` and then restart the server?

Also, after restarting try visiting the link in incognito just to make sure it's not a caching issue.

As Medium explains further on in that tutorial:

> For development purposes, we use something called as debug mode. When `debug=True` is set the server restarts as we add new code to our Flask Application.

Answer (score 0):

So, I tried all of these and nothing worked. Then I restarted the computer and it still didn't work. And then I restarted is 2 more times and it worked, so I don't know what happened.